# 2 random variables - constant height circle - conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

Given is the joint density function:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} C & (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 \leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Obviously C can easily be calculated: $1/\pi$
It's also obvious that this describes a circle with diameter 2 in the x-y-plane (with constant height of $1/\pi$) with it's center at (1,1)

Now the question is to find the conditional probability $P(y \leq x | x \geq 1)$

I think this is solvable by using the bayesian theorem, hence:

$P(y \leq x | x \geq 1) = \frac{P(y \leq x \wedge x \geq 1)}{P(x \geq 1)}$

It's also easy to see that $P(x \geq 1)$ = 1/2

but i can't find out how to calculate $P(y \leq x \wedge x \geq 1)$

Does anyone can give me a hint?